# Bundling mono in 3rd party software

Tags: c#, mono

I have an RPG "game maker" application written in Delphi which emits C++ code.
This C++ code is compiled using the now discontinued and free Borland C++ compiler (commandline edition), which is sadly getting to old for practical use. And since GCC and it's toolchain is a bit of a black art, I have ruled that out as a future option.

So I am investigating what it would take to bundle the mono compiler as part of my own product - and switching to C# as the emitted language instead.

Since my target audience are people with little or no programming skills (except some scripting, which is optional) I really want the installation to be as simple as possible. 
I want to take the files that the standard mono installer provides, but write my own installer. This will ensure that my product doesn't conflict with an already installed version of mono.

So, my question is:
What files/env-variables/registry keys/dll's do i need to "kidnap" to make my mono installation separate? When I look at the directory structure for the standard mono installation, the files seem to be organized in a logical fashion. Everything is stored under a single folder, with only the XUL-runner being registered with the system.
Since I dont need the XUL runner, I presume this can be ignored.

Any help/tips on this is welcome

Comment: Also noticed that the .bat files which is in the mono "bin" folder - are all hardcoded to "C:/program files/mono-x-y-z/bin/".. these would have to be re-written (or omitted since i will call the compiler from my .exe and pipe the text-output back to the IDE)